# Open a terminal, enter an environment, run a script

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

I'm trying to open a terminal, enter an environment, and run a script. The aim is to have a CLI launch in that terminal and environment.

The code I'm trying to use looks something like so...

```
import subprocess

venv = "path/to/my_environment" # Define venv location
command = "source " + venv + "/bin/activate" # Command that enters a venv    
script = "path/to/script/my_script.py" # Example script (`print "Hello World"`)

subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', # Open terminal
                  "--", "bash", "-c", command, # enter environment
                  ";", "--", "python", "-c", script], # run example script
                  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Of course it fails. This is proving hard to overcome because no errors are being given. A terminal opens and immediately closes.

---

**Troubleshooting**:

I know that the following ...

```
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal'])
```

...opens a standard, functional terminal. This is perfect.

I can open a terminal AND run commands...

```
command_a = "echo hello world"
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', "--", "bash", "-c", command])
```

Though I cannot interact with the terminal which is a significant problem. It's locked, which would make it impossible to run a CLI in.

I tried the simplest implementation possible, i.e. just entering my virtual environment:

```
venv = "path/to/my_environment"
command = "source " + venv + "/bin/activate"
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal',
                 "--", "bash", "-c", command])
```

..nothing happens. Even though this is a simple and accurate command.

I also tried combining three simple actions (terminal, command, command) but again, nothing happens...

```
command_a = "echo hello world"
command_b = "echo world is silent"
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', # Open terminal
                 "--", "bash", "-c", command_a, ";", # Run cmd
                 "--", "bash", "-c", command_b]) # Run cmd
```

Just like any attempt to enter a virtual environment, this gives no error message and simply fails to run.

<sub>Someone advised I use [sh](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/index.html#) but despite successfully installing it, python can't import it for some reason. So it's just creating another problem.</sub>

Comment: Starting a terminal, a v-env inside of that, and then running a Python script inside of that, all from within a Python script, is a bit madness, to be honest. And I doubt that is what you should want with subprocess.

Comment: It would make more sense to do all that through a shell script instead.

Comment: You likely can't interact with the terminal launched through subprocess, because subprocess handles stdin, stdout and stderr. So you actually can interact with the terminal through your code, by using subprocess's stdin.

Comment: I can see your point. I was trying to avoid having to write something out in Bash and then MS-DOS. I thought sticking to python to setup my venv, and then moving to it would work.

Comment: MS-DOS?? I see gnome, bash and Unix-style directory separators. Where does MS-DOS come in? Isn't that ancient?

Comment: I'll be honest I don't use windows, I don't think I've ever even used windows powershell. I thought it used MS-DOS. I thought I could use `if platform == 'linux:...` `elif platform == "win32":...`, and that I could have basic script run on both OS's with minimal changes. I'm getting the impression that I have approached this from wholly the wrong angle.

Comment: It depends what you *actually* want to achieve. It seems more logical to have the user launch a terminal that can run a Python script, and let the user activate the virtual-env if necessary. That'll work in all 3 major OSes (plus others like Raspberry PIs as well), and it's up to the user how they set that up (PowerShell should work fine here, and Terminal or iTerm on a Mac also works, instead of starting a gnome-terminal).

Comment: But, as a I said, it depends on your actual goal: *why* do you want to start a terminal, that starts bash, that starts a v-env, that runs a Python script? Why not provide some installation. You could also provide the user some guidelines to set this up (targeted towards various OSes), and let them run the final Python script themselves in the v-env.

Comment: You are correct, it's too complex.

What I want to achieve at the end of the day is a programme that opens in a terminal and runs my CLI. But this isn't a great solution. 

I'm just going to write separate launch scripts for Windows and Nix that will run the python scripts. I have no idea how one goes about doing things properly but this seems less heinous.